# How to change "itemCount" and "initial page" in PageView Builder in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have 3 dart files in my app. 1) main.dart 2) hompage.dart 3) data.dart

There have a singleton class which hold list of string **dataList**.

Using main.dart file i am adding random number of random strings to the the dataList of the singleton class in every 30 seconds.

Now, in homepage there have pageview.builder, in every page build, SinglePage() widgets calls getData(), and get a random string from datList according a left-right page swipes.

**Note : User can only swipe left at most 2 times..**

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rdx_test/data.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Random random = Random();
  DataClass dataClass = DataClass();
  generateStringList(random.nextInt(5)).forEach((noun) {dataClass.addData(noun.toString());});
  Timer(const Duration(seconds: 30), () {
    generateStringList(random.nextInt(5)).forEach((noun) {dataClass.addData(noun.toString());});
  });
  runApp(const HomePage());
}


List<String> generateStringList(int listSize){
  List<String> stringList = [];
  var random = Random.secure();

  for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i ++){
    var values = List<int>.generate(5, (i) =>  random.nextInt(255));
    stringList.add(base64UrlEncode(values));
  }
  return stringList;
}
```

**data.dart**

```
class DataClass {
  static final DataClass _instance = DataClass._internal();
  List<String> dataList = [];
  int lastAccessIndex = 0;


  factory DataClass() {
    return _instance;
  }
  DataClass._internal();

  void addData(String newData){
    dataList.add(newData);
  }
  String? getData(int index){
    if(index < lastAccessIndex){
      return dataList[lastAccessIndex--];
    }else if(index > lastAccessIndex) {
      return dataList[lastAccessIndex++];
    }else{
      return dataList[0];
    }
  }

}
```

**homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rdx_test/data.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return SinglePage(pageIndex: index);
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageIndex;
  const SinglePage({Key? key, required this.pageIndex}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SinglePage> createState() => _SinglePageState();
}

class _SinglePageState extends State<SinglePage> {
  late String word;
  @override
  void initState() {
    DataClass dataClass = DataClass();
    word =  dataClass.getData(widget.pageIndex)!;
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(word));
  }
}
```

It gives me error as i have not mentioned **itemcount**.

So i want to make it dynamic, that whenever new data added to the list it can able to show data or stops the right swipe if no data to be shown..

You can give me suggestion that if this solution can be done in other way like without using singleton class or anything else... THANK YOU...

Comment: I can see it is missing `PageView.builder( itemCount: `

Comment: @YeasinSheikh , yes I have not given itemCount as I don't know the length of list initially.. I want to make that dynamic..

Comment: another thing *User can only swipe left at most 2 times* you can set `itemCount:2`

Answer (score 0):

Use generateStringList in _HomePageState and generate it inside initState method of _HomePageState class.

```
late List<String> generatedStringList;

@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   generatedStringList = generateStringList();
}
```

And then just put `generatedStringList.length` on `itemCount:`;